# Tikz: Finding intersection of Brownian motion and circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I'm trying to draw a two-dimensional Brownian motion started in a circle and now want to label the first exit time of the motion:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}


\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Emmett}[5]{% points, advance, rand factor, options, end label, name
\draw[#4] (0,0)
\foreach \x in {1,...,#1} node(#6)
{   -- ++(rand*#2,rand*#3)
}
node[right] {#5};
}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=left:$x$] (x) at (0,0);
\coordinate [] (y) at (1,1);

\node (D) [name path=D,draw,circle through=(y),label=left:$D$] at (x) {};
\Emmett{300}{0.2}{0.2}{red}{a}{b};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I guess it would be pretty easy with "intersection", if I could name the Brownian motion, but I don't really know how to do that. (Sorry, complete beginner in tikz...)
I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to also apply a `name path` to the Brownian path and find intersections between both paths.

I could do it using the complete command inside the tikzpicture but not using the macro. Probably because the name inside the macro is not public outside, but I'm not sure.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=left:$x$] (x) at (0,0);
\coordinate [] (y) at (1,1);

\node (D) [name path=D,draw,circle through=(y),label=left:$D$] at (x) {};
%\Emmett{300}{0.2}{0.2}{red}{a}{b};
\draw[red, name path=emmet] (0,0) \foreach \x in {1,...,300}{--++(rand*0.2,rand*0.2)};

\fill[green, name intersections={of= emmet and D}] (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]