# One coordinate a function, the other a Brownian Motion

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am new with Tikz and I have a question which I did not manage to solve looking at other posts. I was wondering how to draw a figure in 2D, in which the first component (the *x*) is a function of *x* itself, say for simplicity exp(*x*), while the second is another function of a 1D Brownian motion.

I found some good suggestions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214241/tikz-finding-intersection-of-brownian-motion-and-circle) on how to draw a 2D Brownian motion, but I could not do it on my own. I get stuck if I try to insert a function in the command `{--++(rand*0.2,rand*0.2)}`.

Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you have the brown noise data already?

Comment: I have an idea. Draw a 3D graphic: x axis for x variable, y axis for f(x) and z axis for Brownian motion, then you rotate the graphic to see 2D graphic: f(x) vs Brownian motion ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}


\draw[red] (0,0) \foreach \x in {1,...,300}{--++(0.03,{0.5*(floor(rand)*2.0+1.0)*sqrt(-ln(1-rand^2)/0.627)})};



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: replace `rand*0.2` with `exp(rand*0.2)` if you want `exp` of the Brownian motion.

Comment: @percusse: No, I do not have any data at hand.
@JPi: If I write `\foreach \x in {1,...,300}{--++(0.03,exp(rand*0.2))};`, then it gives this type of error: "Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?" But, in fact, the code is the same as you posted.

Oh, but now I replaced `exp(rand*0.2)` with `exp{rand*0.2}` and now it seems to work.

Comment: @user79476 You should put `{exp(rand*0.2)}` instead of `exp{rand*0.2}`.  Actually it surprises me that the latter even works.

Comment: @user79476 How is this a solution? It is the plot of the random variable from a uniform distribution [-1,1]. Is it OK if it looks random enough? What happened to the `exp(x)` and brown noise?

Comment: Percusse is right; edited.  New version gives an approximate Brownian motion.  Take transformations of that as you please.

Comment: @percusse: I have a process in the (x,y)-plane for which the first coordinate is given by solving a simple ODE and the second a SDE. Apart from that, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @user79476 I still don't see how this is the answer to what you are describing but nevermind, if it works it works.